# Intersection of $n-1$ dimensional subspaces...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$. Show that every one dimensional subspace is the intersection of all $n-1$ dimensional subspaces containing it.

I honestly have no clue on this one.

Comment: I suggest you think about the case of a three dimensional vector space. Can you *see* why every line is the intersection of two planes? If so, then can you *prove* this rigorously? Alex has provided an excellent answer below and it's also worth thinking about his answer geometrically (in the three-dimensional case). What do the two planes look like whose intersection is a line in the case $n=3$ of his answer?

Comment: I can definitely see why a line is the intersection of two planes. I cannot prove it rigorusly. I finished the proof of this today in the general case though. I understand the problem intuitively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Pick a basis $\{x_1\}$ for the line. Extend this to a basis $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Clearly the line is in the intersection of all $n-1$ dimensional subspaces containing it, and to show the converse what if you considered $H_2,\ldots,H_n$ where $H_i=\text{span}\{x_j:j\ne i\}$.

Comment: So then the intersection of all such $H_I$ is in the space generated by $x_1$. Correct?

Comment: Correct. (empty space)

Answer (score 3):

Let the one-dimensional subspace be $V=\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v})$.  If $\mathbf{w} \not\in V$, then $\mathbf{w}$ is a linear combination of $\mathbf{v}$ and a non-zero vector $\mathbf{u}$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$ ($\mathbf{u}$ is the [vector rejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), according to Wikipedia).  If $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n)$, then the $1 \times n$ matrix $$\left(
\begin{matrix}
u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_n \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$ has an $(n-1)$-dimensional [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29), by the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).  Moreover:

- $\mathbf{v}$ is in this null space, since $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are orthogonal.
- $\mathbf{u}$ is not in this null space, otherwise $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}=0$, implying $\mathbf{u}$ is the zero vector.
- Hence $\mathbf{w}$ is not in this null space, otherwise $\mathbf{u}$ could be formed from a linear combination of $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Thus, for any $\mathbf{w} \not\in V$, we have found an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace containing $V$ but not $\mathbf{w}$.

The converse is true by definition (if $\mathbf{w} \in V$, then its in all $(n-1)$-subspaces contain $V$, and hence their intersection also contains $V$).